# Reuse properties from a remote JSON schema, at the same level of the original schema

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I have a remote schema "**person.json**", saved on another file.

```
{
    "id":"#person",
    "type":"object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {"type":"string"},
        "gender": {
            "type":"string",
            "enum":["m", "f"]
        },
        "age": {"type":"number"}
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

And I have a "**man.json**" schema, being this one my original schema.

```
{
    "id":"#man",
    "type":"object",
    "$ref":"person.json",
    "properties": {
        "beard":"boolean",
        "moustache":"boolean"
    },
    "required": ["name"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I want to use the properties: "name, gender, etc" from person.json ***at the same level*** as the properties: "beard, moustache" from man.json.

**Example for validation**

```
{
    name: 'John',
    gender: 'm',
    age: 29,
    beard: false,
    moustache: true
}
```

I want to validate the previously shown example, as you see, with all the properties at the same level (not nested).

Is this possible? If yes, how? Thank you very much.

João

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `allOf` keyword, combined with `$ref`:

```
{
    "id": "/schemas/man.json",
    "allOf": [{"$ref": "person.json"}],
    ...
}
```

*(Note: This is v4.  In v3, the same thing was called `extends`.)*

In plain English, it says "Every instance following Man schema must also follow the Person schema".

The bigger issue is in fact your use of `additionalPropeties`.  Since `person.json` bans additional properties, any instance with a `"beard"` property is actually **not a valid Person**.   If you're going to be extending Person, I advise you remove the constraint banning additional properties.

*(Note: this behaviour is the subject of some conflict in the JSON Schema community, but this is what's in the specs.)*

Comment: It's a shame, json doesn't support such an important feature. I can't discard the "additional properties = false". I used some duplicate code. It's not a good solution, but it works like I want. Thank you.

Comment: A workaround for additionalProperties could be to have kind of an abstract baseclass for person; An abstractPerson class that doesn't forbid additionalProperties, that can be included with allOf into both person and man.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a piece of data cannot satisfy two schemas at once, so you'll need to create a third schema which combines them and validate against that.

```
var personSchema = JSON.parse(person_json);
var manSchema = JSON.parse(man_json)

for (var personProp in personSchema.properties) {
    manSchema.properties[personProp] = personSchema.properties[personProp];
}

var manPersonSchema = JSON.stringify(manSchema);
```

Comment: Your solution seems nice. The only problem is I have my schemas in different files. It would be more difficult than that to fetch them and them merge them. I did it another way. Thanks anyway.